# PHP $_POST Problem

Tags: php, post

i have problem at php $_POST code. this is the my codes? what i do wrong?

this is index.php

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" id="form">
<input type="text" name="fname" size="87" />
<input type="submit" style="display:none" />
```

if i click the submit, page going to upload.php and white screen. and i look at the sample.txt, it's like a:

```
<h1></h1>
```

this is upload.php

```
$yazi=$_POST['fname'];
$fo = fopen("sample".".txt", "a");
fwrite($fo, '<h1>'.$yazi.'</h1>');
fclose($fo);
```

what can i do for fix?
and i using jquery submit. so not a problem display:none, i think.

Comment: You don't have a closing `</form>` tag in index.php.  Also, you did try to type something in the field, right?  Oh, and you un-hid the submit button, right?

Comment: also sample in your fopen() function should be quoted like "sample"

Comment: lol you're allowed to click hidden submit ?

Comment: change `fwrite($fo, '<h1>'.$yazi.'</h1>');` to `fwrite($fo, "<h1>$yazi</h1>");` you don't need to ''.'' everything (like your sample.txt part should be just 'sample.txt'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong happening, the white screen is how it should be working.

After you are done processing in `upload.php`, you can redirect the browser somewhere with the Location header directive. For example:

```
header("Location: http://mypage.com/where_to_go_after.php");
```

The empty $var problem, try using `"` like:

```
fwrite($fo, "<h1>".$yazi."</h1>");
```

Comment: No but you haven't any `echo()` or `print` in your upload.php. So there won't be something output.

Comment: i can't understand. every time, <h1></h1> is empty.. wtf? i want to write it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$fo = fopen(sample.".txt", "a");
```

To

```
$fo = fopen("sample.txt", "a");
```

Complete code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

$filename = 'sample.txt';
$yazi = '<h1>'.$_POST['fname'].'</h1>';

if (is_writable($filename)) {
    if (!$fo = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
         echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
         exit;
    }
    if (fwrite($fo, $yazi) === FALSE) {
        echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
        exit;
    }
    echo "Success, wrote ($yazi) to file ($filename)";
    fclose($fo);
} else {
    echo "The file $filename is not writable";
}
?>
```

Comment: Going on context, perhaps OP should really have `$fo = ($yazi . ".txt", "a");`

Comment: The OP says there is text in 'sample.txt', though he really should do this anyway.  PHP will let you use unquoted strings, but it will give a warning.

Comment: @Joel Etherton: Most probably. 
@umuur: Do you get any error, or it's just that the text is not in the file? 
@Rocket: Maybe there was text from a previous successful attempt.

Comment: i'm trying but it's empty again.

Comment: What was the output when you submitted the form? What did it say? Try again with the added `var_dump()` at the top.

Comment: @umuur: Check your `php.ini`, tell me what is the value for `post_max_size`?

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 2M -it's not post_max_size,

Comment: @umuur: `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are two different things, please look for `post_max_size`.

Comment: i can't see the post_max_size. i'm using easyphp

Comment: Okay, put this in a PHP file and tell me what does it display: `<?php var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size')); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in your code that would prevent the form field from ending up in the file so the error is most likely somewhere else. Here you are a couple of tricks you can use to help you find the issue:

1. Add this on top of all your scripts:

   ```
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ```
2. Add this on top of `upload.php`:

   ```
   var_dump($_POST);
   ```

   ... and go to your browser's "View-> Source" menu to see what your data looks like.
3. Validate your generated HTML with the [W3C online validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: using var_dump im getting array
  empty

Comment: @umuur Right, that means that you can completely ignore `upload.php` by now. Is that your complete HTML form?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify first you $_POST method before performing the action to upload.php

```html
<php>
  if(isset($_POST['fname'])){
    //your echo or any code here..
    //this is to test your method
  }
?>
```